# cloning existing repo and creating react-app

Tags: reactjs, github, gitlab

So I got a little bit confused. I have to clone a remote repo which contains only an `asset` folder. Create a new branch, work on it, and then push to that repo. The only problem is, I have to use `creat-react-app`. So my question is, what is the right order of git commands?

```
1. git clone "repository name" 
2. create-react-app .
3. git branch "branch name" 
4. git checkout "branch name" 
5. git push origin "branch name".
```

Please let me know if I'm thinking correctly. Many thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after cloning:

1. create a new branch and switch to the branch
2. pull from origin to keep your branch up-todate
3. create-react-app . add changes and commit
4. push to remote branch

   ```
    1. git clone "repository name" 
    2. git checkout -b "branch name"
    3. git pull origin <default branch> # pull from origin to keep you up to date
    4. create-react-app .
    5. git add .
    6. git commit -m "your msg"
    7. git push origin "branch name"
   ```